# How to use a constructor parameter within the same constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to use a constructor parameter `some_function` as parameter to a default initialization of some other constructor parameter, namely `some_other_function`:

```
SomeConstructor(SomeFunction some_function,
                SomeOtherFunction some_other_function = SomeOtherFunction(some_function)) :
      some_function_(some_function),
      some_other_function_(some_other_function) 
{...}
```

Unfortunately, this gives a compile error:

```
error: 'some_function' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: You can't do that, C++ does not support it.

Comment: Put an assignment into the body of the constructor, instead of doing it as a default initialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do it without the syntactic sugar(*):

```
Constructor (A a, B b)
  : a_(a), b_(b) {
  // ...
}
Constructor (A a)
  : Constructor (a, B(a)) {}
```

Though this only works since C++11, the feature is known as *delegating* or *forwarding* constructors.

---

(*) "syntactic sugar" isn't really the correct term here, as it's not semantically equivalent to the constructor with the default argument. (Default parameters are - as far as I know - inserted as "normal" parameters at the call site.)

Comment: I know this as "delegating constructors". Indeed, the wording "syntactic sugar" isn't fully correct here, I'll try to clarify that a bit.

Comment: Any reason for retracting the up vote? Is something missing from the answer?